# Android optimized library for ms office documents creation

Tags: java, android

I am looking for an android optimized library that can create, read, modify MS office documents, in particular word documents (docx, doc) and preferably excel documents (xlsx, xls).
Any suggestion besides Apache POI and doc4j ?